# PHP date diff discrepancy

Tags: php

The following PHP code correctly calculates that the number of days between 1st January **1900** and 1st January **1901** is 365 days.

```
    $dateA = new \DateTime('1900-01-01');
    $dateB = new \DateTime('1901-01-01');
    echo $dateA->diff($dateB)->days;
    //result 365 days
```

However, using the same code to calculate the number of days between 1st January **1900** and 1st January **1902** results in less than 365 * 2 days. Calculating the number of days be between 1st January **1901** and 1st January **1902** also results in 364 days. Why is this?

```
    $dateA = new \DateTime('1900-01-01');
    $dateB = new \DateTime('1902-01-01');
    echo $dateA->diff($dateB)->days;
    //result 729 days - WHAT THE....?
```

PHP v. 5.6.12

Comment: [Are you sure](https://3v4l.org/gWrJc)?

Comment: Checked multiple times on my windows PHP env.

Comment: 730 - https://eval.in/479901

Comment: look like specific to win, or to this php ver

Comment: Not specific to Win itself.... just tried it on php5.3.27, 5.4.7, 5.4.21, 5.5.5 and 5.6.0RC4 on my Windows8 laptop and all give correct result.... may be a specific version of Windows though

Comment: Thanx, I'll try to check it again after updating PHP

Comment: So... which time zone is being used with your `DateTime` calculations? For `UTC` it gives the correct result of `730`.

Comment: Reworded to make the question more clear and understandable.